# what are the different testings like DST, Wanem......?

Tags: testing, regression-testing, smoke-testing, manual-testing

can anybody explain the what are the different testings like DST,Wanem.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Could you give us some more information. Your question is too vauge. Check out http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html for tips on how to ask good questions. It'll improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: What type of testing do you wish to perform?

Answer (score 0):

the WANem enables you to do performance tests like simulating different connection speeds. For example you can simulate VPN, 3G, ISDN, DSL speeds to see if your application is still reacting in a timely fashion.

WANem is free, based on linux, and acts like a router.
there are several other testing tools out there (software and hardware based).

Answer (score -1):

I think **DST** and **Wanem** both are different set of words.

DST stands for "DayLight Saving Time" which is related to Day and Time, Many countries use DST to make better use of the daylight in the evenings. you can find more information over here http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/

Wanem stands for "Wide Area Network Emulator", which is related to internet or remote network, for information for this find over here http://sourceforge.net/projects/wanem/files/Documents/wanemulator_all_about_v2.0.pdf/download?use_mirror=kaz

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question as daylight savings time clearly doesn't have anything to do with testing. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).